# Is there a way to adjust the size of the selected anchor points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I am able to rotate a group of selected anchor points of a shape-- either by picking or clicking and dragging on selected anchor points using the direct selection tool then rotate it by using the Rotate Tool.

Is there a way to adjust the size of the selected anchor points?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't change the size of an anchor point in Illustrator at all other than the preference item to display them larger (but they all look about the same to me)...

[image]

If you want to change the *length* of bezier handles on an anchor point, you can select anchors and then use the **Scale Tool** to change handle lengths. It's not the same as "adjusting the size of an anchor" but it may be what you are after. That's the only thing I can think of.